# Array to binary format

Tags: c, arrays, matlab, matrix

I will implement a function that exports one of three arrays to a binary .mat file in double format. The .mat file must be able to be loaded by MATLAB.

```
int exportMAT(const char *filename, const char var, const double result[], int length)
{

typedef struct
{
    uint32_t type;          
    uint32_t mrows;
    uint32_t ncols;
    uint32_t imagf;
    uint32_t namelen;

} Fmatrix;

Fmatrix header;

header.type=0;          
header.mrows=length;    
header.ncols=1;         
header.imagf=0;         
header.namelen=2;       

FILE *fileptr;                  
fileptr=fopen(filename, "w");   

char temp ='\0';
```

// I understand the code but this is a bit unclear to me. What happens in the 4 rows bellow and can you tell me whats inside the brackets?

```
fwrite(&header, sizeof(Fmatrix),1, filptr);     
fwrite(&var, sizeof(char), 1, filptr);          
fwrite(&temp, sizeof(char), 1, filptr);         
fwrite(result, sizeof(dubble), length, filptr); 


fclose(fileptr);        
return length;          

}
```

// Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried searching for and reading about [`fwrite`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite)?

Comment: [This library](https://bitbucket.org/spiros/matfile) for matlab file i/o in c++ might be of interest to you.